# Trying to detect all the circles with HoughCircles in openCV (python)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, detection

I am following this tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/

I was playing around with the parameters ( even those you don't see in the code ex: param2) of HoughCircles and it seems very innacurate, in my project, the disks you see on the picture will be placed on random spots and i need to be able to detect them and their color.

Currently i am only able to detect few circles, and sometimes some random circles are drawn where there is no circles so i am a bit confused.

Is this the best way to do circle detection with openCV or is there a more accurate way of doing it ?
Also why is my code not detecting every circles ?

Initial board : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ba6H9.jpg

Circle drawn : https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dY4q.jpg

My code :

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img = cv2.imread('Photos/board.jpg')
output = img.copy()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)
# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles[0, :]).astype("int")
    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles:
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)
    # show the output image
    cv2.imshow("output", np.hstack([img, output]))
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you can not expect `HoughCircles` to detect all circles in different type of situations. It is not an AI. It has different parameters according to get desired results. You can check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.3.0/d3/de5/tutorial_js_houghcircles.html) to learn more about those parameters.

`HoughCircles` is a contour based function so you should be sure the contours are being detected properly. In your example I am sure bad contour results will come up because of the lighting problem. Metal materials cause light explosion in image processing and this affects finding contours badly.

What you should do:

- Solve the lighting problem
- Be sure about the `HoughCircle` parameters to get desired output
- Instead of using `HoughCircle` you can detect each contour and their mass center ( [moments](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d49/tutorial_moments.html) help you to find their mass center). Then you can measure each length of contour points to that mass center if all equal then its a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Hough transform works best on monochromatic/binary image, so you may want to preprocess it with some sort of threshold function. Parameter values for the function are very important for proper recognition.

> Is this the best way to do circle detection with openCV or is there a more accurate way of doing it ? Also why is my code not detecting every circles ?

there's also `findContours` function
https://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0
which, to my liking, is more robust and general; you may want to give it a try

Comment: thanks for informations, also what if the color of the pucks will be important ?

Comment: @codetime Then you`ll need some way of filtering out objects of ifferent colors, e.g. `inrange` cv2.core function. This actually may greatly improve outcomes you`re getting, since this allows for more agressive preprocessing (much of the background will be culled, noice supressed etc.); *generality* will be negatively affected, though, because selecting colors will bind you to the selected colors. There`s an interesting demo of this approach at https://youtu.be/WQeoO7MI0Bs?t=3374