# OpenCV Hough Circle Transform doesn't detect most circles

Tags: python, opencv, geometry

I am trying to detect as many circles in my images using the following code:

```
maxRadius = int(1.2*(width/16)/2)
minRadius = int(0.9*(width/16)/2)
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
circles = cv.HoughCircles(image=gray, 
                               method=cv.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                               dp=1.2, 
                               minDist=2*minRadius,
                               param1=70,
                               param2=0.9,
                               minRadius=minRadius,
                               maxRadius=maxRadius                           
                          )
```

Although it does work for some of the images there are a few exceptions for which it doesn't.

Below we can see that for two different images that represent the same kind of experiment, my algorithm yields very different results.

How can I fix this? Should I apply some sort of filter on the images first to enhance the contrast?

[image]

[image]

EDIT: added original image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FL5N.jpg)

Comment: Can you please post the test image you are working with? The ones you have posted are too small to work with.

Comment: Post the original images without the scales.

Comment: I think `HoughCircle` shouldn't be the way to solve this. I also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65895764/trying-to-detect-all-the-circles-with-houghcircles-in-opencv-python/65896615#65896615) about that to deal with houghcircle.

Comment: @KnightForked I just added the original image!

Comment: @fmw42 just added the original image!

Comment: You might use adaptive thresholding or division normalization then hough circle to find the most probable ones. Then get the centers and radii. Then given the pattern of centers and the size of your dish, you could partition as many circle as you want into the dish size. Alternately, you might have better  luck trying to find the cells in the circles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution may or may not work on other images but it does work on the one you posted. You might want to work on that "sweet spot" apropos the adaptiveThreshold and HoughCricles parameters so that it works with other images as well.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rgb = cv2.imread('/path/to/your/image/cells_0001.jpeg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imh, imw = gray.shape

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,11,2)

maxRadius = int(1.2*(imw/16)/2)
minRadius = int(0.9*(imw/16)/2)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image=th, 
                               method=cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 
                               dp=1.2, 
                               minDist=2*minRadius,
                               param1=70,
                               param2=25,
                               minRadius=minRadius,
                               maxRadius=maxRadius                           
                          )

out_img = rgb.copy()
for (x, y, r) in circles[0]:
    # draw the circle in the output image
    cv2.circle(out_img, (x, y), int(r), (0, 255, 0), 1)

plt.imshow(out_img)
```

Comment: @Jeanne Chaverot, was this code of any help?

Comment: Hello, sorry just saw your comment. Yes indeed it worked thank you very much!